# Best way to add user to `plugdev` group in an LDAP environment

Tags: ubuntu, group, ldap

I have an LDAP environment for the authentication of users in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS-based network (all clients and servers are Ubuntu 14.04 based systems). My problem is that a specific user actually needs to be added to the `plugdev` group for access to specific hardware that is plugged in via USB.

However, because my environment is LDAP-based auth, I cannot do the usual commands (e.g., [this way](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-add-user-to-group/)).

My LDAP DB, however, is configured to add groups only starting 1000 (of which 1000--1003 are already used up). `plugdev` however is GID 46.

There are two ways by which I can fix this; I am looking for your input to decide which way is "safer."

(a) Change the GID value of the `plugdev` on the client system (e.g., in `/etc/group` by manually editing the file) where I expect to use the specific USB HW device, OR

(b) Change LDAP config to accept lower GIDs (in `/etc/phpldapadmin/config.php` in the LDAP server), and then create a group `plugdev` in LDAP, and set its GID to 46. Then, I have to add `plugdev` LDAP group to my LDAP profile.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I figured this one out. All I had to do was add, on the client machine, my username as one of the users for the group `plugdev` like so:

```
plugdev:x:46:username
```